# SSIS Script Component calling Azure Translator API throws a Buffer Disconnected

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using an SSIS Script component to translate table rows from German into English using Azure Cognitive Services Translator API .

The API returns the translation correctly. But the auto-created file BufferWrapper.cs throws a Dts.Pipeline.BufferDisconnectedException.

The Microsoft documentation for calling the API specifies the main API call method as:

`static async Task Main(string[] args)`

Meanwhile the SSIS Script component auto-created method for processing each row of a table is defined as:

`public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)`

I think my issue is how to reconcile/integrate these two methods.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    

    private static readonly string subscriptionKey = "###########";
    private static readonly string endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
    private static readonly string location = "global";
   

   
    public override async void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        string route = "/translate?api-version=3.0&from=de&to=en";
        
        // get text and convert to Json
        string textToTranslate = Row.TextToTranslate;
        object[] body = new object[] { new { Text = textToTranslate } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            // Build the request.
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(endpoint + route);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region", location);

            // Send the request and get response.
             HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Read response as a string.
           
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Row.TranslationFromAPI = result;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unlikely to be the core issue, but unless Newtonsoft is in the GAC, the script will fail as SSIS script tasks/components can't re-pull from nuget

Comment: I see the async calls in there, don't you need to await results? Smells like that could be the reason an exception of disconnected buffer is being raised

Comment: I've fixed to await results but it's still giving an exception. I'm using Microsoft documentation on how to call the API.  I'm trying to reconcile that with the SSIS auto-created method.  I've updated my question to explain.  Thanks for any advice you can give.